# Using .Contains() with Appsettings key value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, contains, appsettings

I've below `key value` within my `appsettings` -

```
<add key="BlockAMPPages" value="current.aspx, error.aspx, videos.aspx"/>
```

& want to `achieve` below using the above `key value` -

If my `RedirectURL` contains any of the above `string [i.e.keyvalue]` then i want to `return false/or do nothing.`

e.g.

```
RedirectURL- abc.mer.com/abc/error.aspx --> return exist
RedirectURL- abc.mer.com/abc/videos.aspx --> return exist
RedirectURL- abc.mer.com/abc/current.aspx --> return exist
RedirectURL- abc.mer.com/abc/post.aspx --> return not exist.
```

I tried below code in `C#` but no luck-

```
RedirectURL.Contains(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlockAMPPages"].ToString());

RedirectURL.Contains(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlockAMPPages"].ToString().split(','));
```

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: where is your if condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Remove spaces from your configuration value: `current.aspx,error.aspx,videos.aspx`.

Although, this is handled, but it will reduce one extra processing step of `Trim()`

Then try the below code:

```
string blockedPages = "current.aspx,error.aspx,videos.aspx";
string url = "abc.mer.com/abc/error.aspx";

var doesExist = blockedPages.Split(',').Any(x => url.Contains(x.Trim()));
Console.WriteLine(doesExist);
```

Comment: Maybe a Trim as well?

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt, you're matching the URL against the whole app setting string, and a URL will never match the value `current.aspx, error.aspx, videos.aspx`.

In your second example, you're matching `RedirectURL` against an array of elements as a whole (does this even compile? I don't have VS available to test at the moment).

What you need to do, is to match it against all the different types independently, like so:

```
var urlSegmentsToBlock = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlockAMPPages"].ToString().Split(',');

foreach(var urlSegment in urlSegmentsToBlock) 
{
    if(RedirectURL.Equals(urlSegment, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        return false;
}

return true;
```

And also, I'd remove the extra spaces after the commas in your appSetting value, to avoid having to trim the ends of the string you're matching against. So let the value be this: `current.aspx, error.aspx, videos.aspx`.

You could also use [`Any(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) to skip the foreach-loop, but I left the loop in there to make the concept clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In simple form it should something like that:

```
!ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlockAMPPages"].ToString().split(',').Any(pageName=>RedirectURL.Contains(pageName));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `Split` the configuration setting and then you can search for matching conditions using `IndexOf`. Also, **ignoring the case sensitive** could be better.

```
var blockedPages = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlockAMPPages"].Trim(' ').Split(',');
if (blockedPages.Any(x => RedirectURL.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1))
{
    //the RedirectURL contains blocked page
}
else
{

}
```